# If $AB=I_n$ and $BA=I_m$ then $n=m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B$ matrices $n\times m$ and $m\times n$ respectively so that $AB=I_n$ and $BA=I_m$. Show that $n=m$.

Comment: Suppose $n \neq m$. Break it up into cases. First case assume $n>m$ and $m>n$. The use the fact that "if columns of $B$ is linearly dependent then $AB$ is linearly dependent." For both cases you can use this fact to get a contradiction by the Invertible Matrix Theorem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$\newcommand{\tr}{\text{tr}}$ For a square $k\times k$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ we have the trace defined as 
$$
\tr(A) = a_{11} + a_{22} + \dots + a_{kk}.
$$
That is, the trace of a square matrix is the sum of the diagonal elements. It is [a fact that the](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product) trace of $AB$ is equal to the trace of $BA$:
$$
\tr(AB) = \tr(BA)
$$
for *any* matrices where the product makes sense. Note that $AB$ and $BA$ necessarily need to be square matrices. This fact is not too hard to prove using the definition of the matrix product and the definition of the trace.

Now using this fact, you have
$$
n = \tr(I_n) = \tr(AB) = \tr(BA) = \tr(I_m) = m.
$$

Comment: @Thomas : The result is true in general for matrices over any field. Your proof works good if the field has characteristic zero.

Comment: The result is true in general for matrices over any commutative ring! Unfortunately the above proof can't be used to prove this.

Comment: @nsoum please tell me which fact used in the theorem fails in general field

Comment: @CloudJR: Maybe ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing wrong with Thomas's argument. It's the one I would have used myself. But, I thought I'd add the other "obvious" argument.

Since $AB = I_n$ we know that $A$ has full rank equal to $n$. This is because, for any $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the equation $Ax = b$ has the solution $x = Bb \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Since $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n$, the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) applied to $A$ implies that $m \geq n$.

Similarly, from $BA = I_m$, one deduces $m \leq n$, so $m=n$ as desired.

Comment: It is possibly simpler to say that the conditions in the question mean that $rank(A) = m$ and $rank(A) = n$. Since the rank of a matrix is unique that means $n = m$

Comment: @James: You could also say "the condition of the question is that $A$ and $B$ are inverse linear isomorphisms between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since the dimension of a vector space is an isomorphism invariant, $m=n$".

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$tr(AB) = tr(BA)$;

where $tr(A)$ is the trace of $A$ (sum of diagonal elements in a square matrix).