# Two non-invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB = BA= I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that a square matrix $A$ is called invertible if there exists $B$ such that $AB = BA = I$.

But is it possible to find two matrices $A_{m \times n}$ and $B_{n \times m}$ such that $AB =I_m$ and $BA = I_n$ ?

(*where $m \neq n$*)

**EDIT :** I just [realized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468685/if-ab-i-n-and-ba-i-m-then-n-m) that if $A$ and $B$ are matrices over a field (like $\mathbb{R}$), then $m=n$. But after reading the comments, I am now interested in knowing what conditions will confirm the presence of such an example where $m \neq n$.

Comment: Yes , possible. In that case instead of inverse, you have left inverse and right inverse separately.

Comment: Not over a field, but possible if the coefficients are in a noncommutative ring.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Could you please give me an example of such a case? It would be better if you write it as an answer.

Comment: Such a $B$ is by definition an inverse of $A$, and the existence of such a $B$ means that $A$ is invertible.  However, over a field, this is impossible when $m\neq n$, because of rank: the dimension of the image of a map cannot be larger than the dimension of the domain, and so $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B))$.  Anything resembling a counterexample would have to be over a ring where rank is not defined or not well behaved.

Comment: So, can we still hope for a counterexample for a ring of characteristic $n-m$?

Comment: Yes, this is possible but later you'll realize that the matrices must be square. 
**Hint**: Perform row/column operations say on $AB = P$
**Intuition**: Product of matrices can be expressed as the linear combination of row/columns and in order to get $I_m$ or $I_n$ this must be square matrices

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
A = \pmatrix{a&&b}_{1\times2}
&  && B = \pmatrix{c\\d}_{2\times1}\\
\text{let } AB  = \pmatrix{ac + bd} = I_1 && BA =  \pmatrix{ac&&cb\\ad&&db} = I_2
\end{align*}$$
So, doesn't exist
This also means that a given(incapable) transformation matrix can't squish a vector back to what it was before.(inverse)

Comment: @I_don't_know_maths: I disagree, there are rectangular examples over a noncommutative ring, see my answer.

Comment: @GreginGre [Nice!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320844/two-non-invertible-matrices-a-and-b-such-that-ab-ba-i/4321011#4321011) but I'm unable to find how could $cb =0 \implies c \text{ or } b = 0$ but $a_{11} \ne 0 \implies c \ne 0 $ which implies $b = 0$ if so then $a_{22} = 0$
In short how could ($a_{12} = 0$ ∩  $a_{22} \ne 0$ ∩ $a_{11} \ne 0$) be true

Comment: The point is my ring $R$ has zero divisors. More precisely, $R$ has left/right zero divisors which are not right/left zero divisors.  Note that over a division ring $R$, you cannot have rectangular invertible matrix (it is not totally immediate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the comments, this is not possible if the coefficients of your matrices live in a commutative ring with unit.

However, it is possible if the base ring is noncommutative.

As an explicit example, let $R={\rm End}_K(K[X])$, where $K$ is an arbitrary field.

Note that $R$ is a noncommutative ring with unit, where $1_R=Id$, and product is composition of maps (and $0_R$ is the zero map).

Let $x,y,\alpha,\beta:K[X]\to K[X]$ the $K$-linear maps defined by:

$$x(\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nX^n)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{2n+1}X^n, \ y(\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nX^n)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{2n}X^n$$

$$\alpha(\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nX^n)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nX^{2n+1}, \ \beta(\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nX^n)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nX^{2n}$$

I let you check that we have the following identities in the ring $R$:

- $\alpha x+\beta y=1$
- $x\alpha=1$ and $x\beta=0$
- $y\alpha=0$ and $y\beta=1$

Now set $A=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta\end{pmatrix}\in M_{1\times 2}(R)$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}x \cr y\end{pmatrix}\in M_{2\times 1}(R)$. Then, the relations above imply that $AB=I_1$ and $BA=I_2$.

Comment: Nice answer! How did you rule out matrices over unitary commutative rings completely?

Comment: Take a maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ (which exists since $R$ is commutative), so $K=R/M$ is a field. Now, if $M=(m_{ij})$ is any (possibly rectangular) matrix with entries in $R$, set $\bar{M}=(\bar{m}_{ij})$. This is a matrix with entries in $K$. The operation $M\mapsto \bar{M}$ is compatible with sum and product, and sends identity matrix to identity matrix. So if $AB=I_n$ and $BA=I_m$, where $A\in M_{n\times m}(R)$ and $B\in M_{m\times n}(R)$,  applying this operation says $\bar{A}$ is an invertible matrix of $M_{n\times m}(K)$, hence $n=m$ since $K$ is a field.